# Secure WebSocket Connection (WSS) Through Domain SSL Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, websocket, wildfly

I have a very private problem, I have a Java EE application (WildFly 10), running on the infrastructure of Amazon, well.

This application has an SSL certificate acquired of a specific domain ("www.xxx.com"), which has been properly installed on Amazon's Application Load Balancer (ALB), which retains requests and forwards securely to the application server an EC2, so far everything great.

But when we try to instantiate in the pages a "client" "WebSocket" in JavaScript it even presents "MixedContent" errors when used via unsecured WebSocket (WS), so that's fine because it is a browser security requirement:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://<ip-address>:8080/web-socket");
```

So i use a secure WebSocket (WSS) to make the connection, then under the IP and then presented the error that the IP was not secure because it had not been certified:

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://<ip-address>:8443/web-socket");
```

So I installed the SSL certificate of the domain on the WildFly 10 server, but even then the error was still presented because the SSL certificate was purchased for the domain, not for the IP I'm trying to connect.

If i try to connect Secure WebSocket (WSS) through the secure domain, the same connects, but the Amazon ALB always drops it for inactivity time, and even if the value is too high, the Time to Live (TTL) over time, it shows performance loss over time, I believe by pooling TCP connections.

```
ws = new WebSocket("wss://www.xxx.com.br:8443/web-socket");
```

A possible solution would be to buy an SSL certificate that instead of registering a domain, would be registered under the IP of the server, the same would be installed on the server to allow this secure connection between Secure WebSocket and Secure Application, what opinion or experience you?

Comment: Any reason why your not using the AWS certificate manager to generate and attach the cert to the ALB? If this is possible you can create the cert in the AWS certificate manager and this will generate an ARN. You can then link that ARN to your ALB and AWS will manage the cert, updating, etc etc. It doesn't cost anything.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the purchased certificate is being used in ALB through Amazon's Identity and Access Management (IAM), that is, I am already linking the SSL certificate to the ALB.

The question itself and that the certificate was purchased for a domain (www.xxx.com), however I want to connect a Secure WebSocket (WSS) to the server directly without going through the ALB, that is through IP, but WSS only accepts if the certificate is valid, but the certificate is from the domain and not from the IP.

Comment: I see. Why do you want to bypass the ALB? AWS ELB/ALB now supports WebSockets. Could you explain why you are bypassing the ALB to use the instance directly?

Comment: Yes, now I modified for the ALB in the hope of resolving the issue, I previously used the ELB.

But when I request that Secure WebSocket (WSS) connect through the domain, rather than IP, it works.

But ALB has "Idle timeout" that knocks down WebSocket because of inactivity, and if I put it with a very long time 3600 seconds it generates a very large accumulation of sections, and if I put a manual check to keep the connection always active in the browser, the ALB itself refuses the successive connections because of the constant activity checks.

Comment: This was the reason I skipped ALB in the case of WebSocket, because "Idle timeout" in WebSockets in ALB.

Comment: How long before your ALB causes a timeout? Why is 60 seconds of inactivity not a valid timeout for you? Why should a websocket be sitting inactive for longer than that? If the browser fails to connect then in JavaScript or in your WS client you should have logic to simply establish a new connection if the last one has timed out or is invalid....By connecting directly to the instance your creating the same scenario as setting the timeout very high because your preventing real idle connections from being killed.